# Automatically fix case usage in table and column names from Access to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, ms-access

I am converting an existing MS Access application to use a MariaDB backend running on CentOS 7. I used a tool from BullZip to convert the Access database to MySQL.

After that I used another tool to export all the Access queries to file, and with some simple string replacing (like replacing square braces with backticks, replacing `Iif` with `IF`, etc) I could run most of the queries out of the box against my MariaDB version.

The problem now lies with the more complicated queries. The original software developer didn't really pay much attention to upper/lower case usage, so a table called `Foo` could be addressed in Access like `SELECT .. FROM foo`.

Are there any tricks on converting those queries in a proper way, that do live sanity checks to the actual database? Doing all this manually is **A LOT of work**, since the original programmer created about 5000 (!) different queries.

I tried setting `lower_case_table_names` in the MariaDB configuration, but after that the database becomes unusable. It suddenly says I can't connect to the database anymore. And besides that, I think I do want the system to be case sensitive anyway, since that avoids conflicts IMHO.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli I'm not sure how I can improve my question any further. I am looking for a tool/way to automate the conversion of the MS Access queries to MySQL, whilst also fixing the usage of correct upper/lowercase spelling in table and column names. Do you maybe have some pointers for me on how to improve the question to make that more clear ?

Comment: Use Workbench to do the conversion.

Comment: @RickJames I can't seem to find a function in MySQL Workbench to convert an entire batch (4000) .SQL files with MS Access (T-SQL?) queries to MySQL formatted ANSI SQL.

Comment: Are you aiming for MySQL?  Or MariaDB?  MariaDB is closer to ANSI.

Comment: @RickJames I'm running MariaDB